# How to improve the convergence of a stochastic differential equation?

Tags: stochastic-processes, numerical-methods, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, numerical-calculus

I have a stochastic differential equation, i.e,

$$ d\rho_t= \hat{A} \rho_s dt + \hat{B} \rho_s \nu dt + \hat{C}\rho_s\omega_{1t} dt + \hat{D}\rho_s \omega_{2t}dt  \quad  , \quad  t>s $$

Here A, B, C and D are operators. $\nu$ is a white noise.  $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ are color noises with specific correlation matrices.  As we know that there are several methods to improve the convergence of a SDE,  for example,

1) Decrease the number of noises

2) Use higher order numerical algorithms (Range Kutta etc.)

3) Use small time steps and large number of trajectories

Now, apart from above mentioned techniques, is there any other way to decrease the fluctuations of a SDE if we directly simulate it numerically with Euler or Range Kutta algorithms?

Comment: Why do you have 3 noise terms? You can combine them to one noise term. Ito or Stratanovich? Why not use the exact solution formula of the geometric Brownian motion?

Comment: yes i know, the above equation is just an example. I am not talking about exact solution. I am talking about if we do it numerically. The number of noises will play the role in convergence. In my actual equation, i can not decrease my noises,   there are white noises and color noises which can't be combined